# printing text without use of format string in bash

Tags: bash, printf

Have been doing `printf "text"` to print some text from a bash script.  Is using `printf` without a format string valid to do?

Comment: That is a format string. It just doesn't happen to contain any format operators.

Comment: If you're asking about `printf "$variable"`, that's a bad idea. You should use `printf "%s" "$variable"`

Comment: Yes but when you don't need formatting text simply use the `echo` command instead of `printf`

Comment: Was not using `printf "$variable"` but inputting some information directly,

Comment: @Alireza `echo` is a poor alternative to `printf`.

Comment: Does echo support coloured output?  Had been using `tput` with `printf` to print in colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the entire message in the format string is a reasonable thing to do provided it doesn't contain any dynamic data. As long as you have full control over the string (i.e. it's either just a fixed string, or one selected from a set of fixed strings, or something like that), and you've used that control to make sure it doesn't contain any unintended escape characters, all `%` characters in it are doubled (making them literal, rather than format specifiers), and the string doesn't start with `-`.

Basically, if it's a fixed string and it doesn't obviously fail, it'll work consistently.

But if it contains any sort of dynamic data -- filenames, user-entered data, anything at all like that -- you should put format specifiers in the format string, and the dynamic data in separate arguments.

So these are ok:

```
printf 'Help, Help, the Globolinks!\n'
printf 'Help, Help, the %s!\n' "$monster_name"
```

But this is not:

```
printf "Help, Help, the $monster_name!\n"    # Don't do this
```